# Pandas dataframe divide features to group of high correlation

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, feature-selection, yellowbrick

I have a dataframe with over 280 features.
I ran correlation map to detect groups of features that are highly correlated:
[image]
Now, I want to divide the features to groups, such that each group will be a "red zone", meaning each group will have features that are all have correlation >0.5 with each other.

How can it be done?

Thanks

Comment: I think it may be possible for the groups to intersect. Say, feature [A,B,C] form a red group, [C,D,E] form a red group but [A,B,C,D,E] do not. How do you deal with such situation?

Comment: @BillHuang I want that all the features will be "red" with other, within each group. so in the case you suggested - one group is [A,B,C] and one group is [C,D,E]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer**:

1. Visualization is not addressed in this solution. Only groups were found.
2. The solution is known to be NP-hard, so mind efficiency problems.

### Theory

The problem is essentially a [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem) in graph theory, which means finding all the complete subgraphs in a given graph (with nodes > 2).

Imagine a graph that all the features are nodes and pairs of features satisfying `corr > 0.5` are edges. Then the task of finding all "groups" requested can simply translates into "finding all complete subgraphs in the graph".

### Code

The code uses [networkx.algorithms.find_cliques](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html) for the search task, which implements [Bron–Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) according to the docs.

The code conprises of two parts. The first part extract the edges using `np.triu` (modified from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417685)) and the second part feeds the edge list into `networkx`.

**The Coorelation Matrix**

Feature [A,B,C] and [C,D,E] are closely correlated respectively, but not between [A,B] and [D,E].

```
np.random.seed(111)  # reproducibility
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 100)
a = x
b = x + np.random.normal(0, .5, 100)
c = x + y
d = y + np.random.normal(0, .5, 100)
e = y + np.random.normal(0, .5, 100)

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":a, "B":b, "C":c, "D":d, "E":e})
corr = df.corr()

corr
Out[24]: 
          A         B         C         D         E
A  1.000000  0.893366  0.677333 -0.078369 -0.090510
B  0.893366  1.000000  0.577459 -0.072025 -0.079855
C  0.677333  0.577459  1.000000  0.587695  0.579891
D -0.078369 -0.072025  0.587695  1.000000  0.777803
E -0.090510 -0.079855  0.579891  0.777803  1.000000
```

**Part 1**

```
# keep only upper triangle elements (excluding diagonal elements)
mask_keep = np.triu(np.ones(corr.shape), k=1).astype('bool').reshape(corr.size)
# melt (unpivot) the dataframe and apply mask
sr = corr.stack()[mask_keep]
# filter and get names
edges = sr[sr > 0.5].reset_index().values[:, :2]

edges
Out[25]: 
array([['A', 'B'],
       ['A', 'C'],
       ['B', 'C'],
       ['C', 'D'],
       ['C', 'E'],
       ['D', 'E']], dtype=object)
```

**Part 2**

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.from_edgelist(edges)
ls_cliques = []
for clique in nx.algorithms.find_cliques(g):
    ls_cliques.append(clique)

# result
ls_cliques
Out[26]: [['C', 'A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'E']]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error:
In the line sr = corr.stack()[mask_keep] , I get: 
IndexError: Item wrong length 97344 instead of 78400.

The shape of mask_keep is (97344,), and corr is (312, 312). However, the length of corr_mat.stack() is 78400 which causes the error

Comment: Please clear your entire work space and check your variable names carefully. As indicated by the fact that 78400=280^2, you are likely feeding the new mask onto old data.

Comment: It is also possible that some of the 312 features were not present in the corr matrix (e.g. categorical features). Please remove these features and retry.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue here: the length of the stacked correlation matrix differed from that of the mask.
What worked for me was to keep the NaNs while stacking as follows:

```
sr = corr.stack([dropna=False][1])[mask_keep]
```

@[billhuang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3218693/bill-huang) correctly states reasons why this could happen.