Upper Triangular Matrix from pandas multiindex
Building off the question here:
Melt the Upper Triangular Matrix of a Pandas Dataframe
I am looking to do something similar, but across a multi-index (index level 0 of DF)
Is there a better way of going about this than a for loop?
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# SETUP INPUT
A_1 = [1, .5, .3]
B_1 = [.5, 1, .4]
C_1 = [.3, .4, 1]

A_2 = [1, -.5, -.3]
B_2 = [-.5, 1, -.4]
C_2 = [-.3, -.4, 1]

# SETUP DFs
DF_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': A_1, 'B': B_1, 'C': C_1, 'DATE': '2024-05-23', 'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C']}).set_index(['DATE', 'ID'])
DF_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': A_2, 'B': B_2, 'C': C_2, 'DATE': '2024-05-24', 'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C']}).set_index(['DATE', 'ID'])

DF = pd.concat([DF_1, DF_2])

def prior_solution(df: pd.DataFrame):
    # Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417685/melt-the-upper-triangular-matrix-of-a-pandas-dataframe
    df_filt = df.where(np.triu(np.ones(df.shape)).astype(np.bool_))
    long = df_filt.stack().reset_index()
    long.columns = ['DATE', 'ID1', 'ID2', 'VALUE']
    return long

# get individual pieces - note there sill be an arbitrary number of these, based on DATE in the index of the aggregated df
L_1 = prior_solution(DF_1)
L_2 = prior_solution(DF_2)

# Want
# note ID1 and ID2 pairs are not repeating
WANT = pd.concat([L_1, L_2]

WANT
DATE,ID1,ID2,VALUE
2024-05-23,A,A,1.0
2024-05-23,A,B,0.5
2024-05-23,A,C,0.3
2024-05-23,B,B,1.0
2024-05-23,B,C,0.4
2024-05-23,C,C,1.0
2024-05-24,A,A,1.0
2024-05-24,A,B,-0.5
2024-05-24,A,C,-0.3
2024-05-24,B,B,1.0
2024-05-24,B,C,-0.4
2024-05-24,C,C,1.0


You can .stack() the DataFrame and then compare on the resultant MultiIndex to filter down to the equivalent of the upper triangle.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# SETUP INPUT
A_1 = [1, .5, .3]
B_1 = [.5, 1, .4]
C_1 = [.3, .4, 1]

A_2 = [1, -.5, -.3]
B_2 = [-.5, 1, -.4]
C_2 = [-.3, -.4, 1]

# SETUP DFs
DF_1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': A_1, 'B': B_1, 'C': C_1, 'DATE': '2024-05-23', 'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C']}).set_index(['DATE', 'ID'])
DF_2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': A_2, 'B': B_2, 'C': C_2, 'DATE': '2024-05-24', 'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C']}).set_index(['DATE', 'ID'])

DF = pd.concat([DF_1, DF_2])
print(
    DF
    .rename_axis(index={'ID': 'ID1'}, columns='ID2')
    .stack()
    .loc[lambda d: d.index.codes[-2] <= d.index.codes[-1]]
    .rename('VALUE')
    .reset_index()
)
#           DATE ID1 ID2  VALUE
# 0   2024-05-23   A   A    1.0
# 1   2024-05-23   A   B    0.5
# 2   2024-05-23   A   C    0.3
# 3   2024-05-23   B   B    1.0
# 4   2024-05-23   B   C    0.4
# 5   2024-05-23   C   C    1.0
# 6   2024-05-24   A   A    1.0
# 7   2024-05-24   A   B   -0.5
# 8   2024-05-24   A   C   -0.3
# 9   2024-05-24   B   B    1.0
# 10  2024-05-24   B   C   -0.4
# 11  2024-05-24   C   C    1.0

